# HTML/CSS How to remove a border of a specific Image?

Tags: html, css, image, border

[Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLdBF.png)

I would like to remove the border of the umbrella but also keeping the border of the other images as well.
As for my coding for the image borders this is in my style body.

```
img {
                border: 5px solid #03aaec       ;
          }
```

Here is the code for the Logo/Title and Products

```
<H1><img src="homelogo.png "alt="" style="width: 70px; height: 70px;">Shop</H1>


<img src="product.jpg" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```

Any assistance would be helpful! Thank You!

Comment: use the :not() selector : `img:not([src="homelogo.png"]) {
                border: 5px solid #03aaec       ;
          }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add or remove a border, you must first pick the picture you want to use. Using a class or an id is a good way to go. Then include it in your CSS.

for example:
declaring class name image1:

```
<img class="image1" src="product.jpg" alt="" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
```

then call it to your CSS,

```
.image1{
 /* Manipulating code here */
}
```